# Bootstrap 3.x : display:none for accordion

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add FAQs section in my website using this code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But my  output is displayed for 1 moment and then lost this is what I get from inspect element. Can some one help how `display:none` is being injected in my code  [image]

Comment: You awant an accordeon, so you'll need to set one item as your primary, so he displays that item. The implementation of the hidden style is normal.

Comment: To add a primary (a value that is opened) use this <div class="panel panel-primary"> instead of <div class="panel panel-default">

Comment: Wat rendered content do you have after applying my code?

Comment: same result appears for 1 second and then gone

Comment: This works fine in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/6zj1Lfa3/). You may need to post more info/code. What version of jquery are you using? Bootstrap 3 requires 1.90 or above.

Answer (score 1):

Ok a couple small changes and you're ready to go.

1 - remove class "collapsed" from your first title. (change aria-expanded to true)

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" class="">1. What is HTML?</a>
```

2 - Add class "in" to your first panel body container (and remove aria-expanded from all body containers)

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="height: 0px;">
```

3 - remove inline height style from the first panel body container

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```